# How to Exclude Certain Columns from a Google Apps Script For Loop Calculation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Part of a google apps script I am working on loops through column values and stores data in their location. I want to exclude certain rows from this operation because I do not want the data in those columns to be overwritten.

```
// save back the values from the editor sheet to the master data sheet
var lookUpTable = ss.getRangeByName("Editor_sheet_template!z_saveback_LookupTableOfCellsAndColumnsToSave");
var sourceCellAddress, sourceCellValue, targetCell, targetCellColumn;
// iterate through all rows in the lookup table
for (var cellRow = 1; cellRow <= lookUpTable.getHeight(); cellRow++) {
  // save the value of the editor sheet cell listed in the lookup table to its
  // corresponding column on the master data sheet
  sourceCellAddress = lookUpTable.getCell(cellRow, /* column */ 1).getValue();
  sourceCellValue = editorSheet.getRange(sourceCellAddress).getValue();
  targetCellColumn = lookUpTable.getCell(cellRow, /* column */ 2).getValue();
  if(targetCellColumn != 'A','D','E'){
    Logger.log(targetCellColumn);
    targetCell = masterDataSheet.getRange(targetCellRow, targetCellColumn);
    targetCell.setValue(sourceCellValue);
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting the value of the cell, you want to get the A1 Notation and use the substring method to get the letter. Then your 'if' conditional to check for column A, D, or E should work.

```
// save back the values from the editor sheet to the master data sheet
var lookUpTable = ss.getRangeByName("Editor_sheet_template!z_saveback_LookupTableOfCellsAndColumnsToSave");
var sourceCellAddress, sourceCellValue, targetCell, targetCellColumn;
// iterate through all rows in the lookup table
for (var cellRow = 1; cellRow <= lookUpTable.getHeight(); cellRow++) {
  // save the value of the editor sheet cell listed in the lookup table to its
  // corresponding column on the master data sheet
  sourceCellAddress = lookUpTable.getCell(cellRow, /* column */ 1).getValue();
  sourceCellValue = editorSheet.getRange(sourceCellAddress).getValue();
  targetCellColumn = lookUpTable.getCell(cellRow, /* column */ 2)
    .getA1Notation().substring(0, 1); //this gets the first character of the A1 Notation which is the column letter
  if(targetCellColumn != 'A','D','E'){
    Logger.log(targetCellColumn);
    targetCell = masterDataSheet.getRange(targetCellRow, targetCellColumn);
    targetCell.setValue(sourceCellValue);
  }  
}
```